# How can I run a job that doesn't block subsequent stages in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

In a project I'm running two stages with these jobs:

- `build`

  - `compile & test`
  - `generate sonar report`
- `deploy`

  - `deploy to staging environment` [manual]
  - `deploy to production` [manual]

The jobs in the `deploy` stage depend on the outputs of the `compile & test` job. However the `generate sonar report` job is not required to finish before I can start any job in the `deploy` stage. Nevertheless, GitLab insists that all jobs in the `build` phase have finished before I can launch any job in the `deploy` phase.

Is there a way I can tell GitLab that the `generate sonar report` job should not block subsequent pipeline stages? I already tried `allow_failure: true` on this job but this does not seem to have the desired effect. This job takes a long time to finish and I really don't want to wait for it all the time before being able to deploy.

Answer (score 5):

From my point of view, it depends on your stage semantics. You should try to decide what is mostly important in your pipeline: clarity on stages or get the job done.

GitLab has many handy features like [`needs` keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) you can use it to specify direct edges on the dependency graph.

```yaml
stages:
    - build
    - deploy

build:package:
    stage: build
    script: 
        - echo "compile and test"
        - mkdir -p target && echo "hello" > target/file.txt
    artifacts:
        paths: 
            - ./**/target

build:report:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "consume the target artifacts"
        - echo "waiting for 120 seconds to continue"
        - sleep 120
        - mkdir -p target/reports && echo "reporting" > target/reports/report.txt
    artifacts:
        paths: 
            - ./**/target/reports

deploy:
    stage: deploy
    needs: ["build:package"]
    script:
        - echo "deploy your package on remote site"
        - cat target/file.txt
```

[image: pipeline screenshot exhibiting the deploy executed before the end of build stage]

Answer (score 3):

We have similar situation, and while we do use `allow_failure: true`, this does not help when the Sonar job simply takes a long time to run, whether it fails or succeeds.

Since you are not wanting your `deploy` stage to actually be gated by the outcome of the `generate sonar report` job, then I suggest moving the `generate sonar report` job to the `deploy` stage, so your pipeline would become:

- build

  - compile & test
- deploy

  - deploy to staging environment [manual]
  - deploy to production [manual]
  - generate sonar report [allow_failure: true]

This way the `generate sonar report` job does not delay your `deploy` stage jobs

The other benefit of running `generate sonar report` *after* `build & test` is that you can save coverage reports from the `build & test` job as Gitlab job artifacts, and then have `generate sonar report` job consume them as dependencies, so Sonar can monitor your coverage, too

Finally, we find it useful to separate `build & test` into `build`, then `test`, so we can separate `build` failures from `test` failures - and we can then also run multiple test jobs in parallel, all in the same `test` stage, etc. Note you will need to convey the artifacts from the `build` job to the `test` job(s) via Gitlab job artifacts & dependencies if you choose to do this

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken, this is currently not possible, and there is an [open feature proposal](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/36500), and [another one similar](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/28592) to add what you are suggesting.